# Gamesharing help Xbox 1

Tags: xbox-one

I have my friends (Friend 1) account set to "My Home Xbox" on my Xbox. If I change My Home Xbox to Friend 2 will I lose the game licenses from Friend 1?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  You will have to login to friend 1 as you to use them.  If both friend 1 and friend 2 are logged on, only one of them can be logged on as you.  Your games are tied to your account, not the device.  This allows you to go visit a friend and play your games there. But it doesn't allow you to visit your friend, upload all your games to his/her Xbox and then go home and let them go nuts with $500 in free stuff.

If they log on as you, for example, you'll be locked out of your Xbox until they turn it off.  Then, they'll be locked out, etc.

Make sense?

AFAIK, the home feature mainly exists to store things like your payment details for quick purchasing and the like.  If you log onto a friend's device and try and purchase something, you have to reenter your payment details where the home device saves them and allows you to purchase without constant verification.